# Creating new users in hippo with custom properties

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

When we create users in cms console, i just dony want email, first name last name already provided by cms. I want to add custom properties like phone number or city or user type which arr project specific. I am stuck on this for days. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native cms users can only have the properties they have, as defined in the cnd. Users managed by an external system (like an ldap server) can have any properties, though I'm not sure that would be displayed in user management (they might be, I'd have to check the code). However, those are not directly manageable in the cms, the data belongs to an external system.

If you don't want to use an external directory service like AD, then you might consider creating a document type in the cms. You can store all the information on users there that you want. This can be used for directory purposes, for display on the site, for author bio... Note that the system is not a directory service. If you have large amounts of users that need to be managed then I would recommend using an external service. This may also be useful for security purposes as most directory service also fucntion as IAM services. However, even then it may be useful to create user documents for more detailed information and possibly for historical information if the user is removed from IAM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I have another question. Where is all the user data, blog posts, images we upload gets saved? I have connected my project to mysql but all i could see is just version history etc. Also, is there any tutorial available to learn hippo for enterprise applications which will clear out my doubts and confusion to great extent.

Comment: You should forget about mysql. Mysql is to jcr as a file system is to mysql. If you got to http://localhost:8080/cms/console you can see the repository. There are a number of onine tutorials at https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/trails/demo-tutorials-and-download.html. We also offer trainings, but currently only via internet. In person trainings are out for the forseeable future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. So we cant use mysql to store blog posts, contents etc? Also, could you please give me more info about the online training you provide? Would be happy to join it.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. You store content in the repository. The repository is backed by an rdbms but that is an implemenation detail. You should think of storing a blog post as a document in the repository. These can be created in the cms interface or imported via a rest endpoint. If you want to store data outside of the repository you can, but that is a bit more involved than I can answer in a comment. It may or may not be a valid implementation based on many factors. For our tranings you can look here: https://www.bloomreach.com/en/services/trainings

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jasper :)

Comment: Jasper these trainings are way too costly to buy for a mere developer. I might have access to enterprise edition after my company buys it. At the moment i dont have it. Is there any way I could get some insights of the tutorials?

Comment: Generally the trainings are paid for by employers. The online tutorials we have are free however, and they cover many of the same topics, just without a trainer.